# how to put php variable in header location?

Tags: javascript, php, html

my code is

```
<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION["adm_no"]))
{
    header("Location:<?php echo $homepage; ?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");
    
}
?>
```

I want to pass url through variable, but I am unable to get values from that variable.

Comment: You can't write a php tag inside  php tag

Comment: You should just need `header("Location:$homepage" . "?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");`

Comment: I see no `session_start()`

Comment: I see no code that sets `$homepage`

Comment: You are already in a `<?php` code block so you dont need another one for `header("Location:<?php echo $homepage; ?j.....` Reading to much Wordpress code i expect!

Answer (score 2):

You are putting php tags twice. Try this:

```
<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION["adm_no"]))
{
    header("Location:".$homepage."?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");
}
?>
<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION["adm_no"]))
{
    header("Location:".$homepage."?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");
}
?>
```

Comment: In a double quoted string you dont need to concatenate. you can just do `header("Location:$homepage?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");`

Comment: @RiggsFolly true, thanks. But it doesn't hurt that way either

Comment: Also true, which is why I just made a comment

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open another php opening tags inside the opened one.

```
<?php 
  session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION["adm_no"]))
{
    header("Location:$homepage?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");

}
?>
```

Comment: In a double quoted string you dont need to concatenate. you can just do `header("Location:$homepage?jaxmas=wHgfghks^^%&fnjfskjdfb");`